# Can an empty set be both torsion and torsion-free group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, torsion-groups

I was wondering if an empty set can be a torsion group (since the definition of torsion group is that if $x$ is in the set $X$ has a finite order. However, the assumption is false, so the implication is true) and with same reasoning, torsion-free?

Comment: The empty set is not a group at all, as it does not contain a neutral element.

Answer (score 14):

You probably are confusing the empty set (which is not a group) with the *trivial group*, having only the identity as element. This group is indeed torsion (any element has finite order) and torsionfree (any non identity element has infinite order).

In this way the statements

> every subgroup of a torsionfree group are torsionfree

and

> every quotient of a torsion group is torsion

are valid without restrictions.

Comment: It worth mentioning that, although for the trivial group it is (formally) correct that ∀ *x*: (*x* ≠ *e*) → *x* isn’t a torsion, there are **no such *x* that *x* ≠ *e* .**

Answer (score 11):

The empty set cannot be a torsion group nor can it be a torsion-free group because the empty set cannot be a group.  A group must have an identity element.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

Does an emptyset has an identity element?

Answer (score 0):

The empty set is not a group because there is no identity element. I think maybe you are confused about the definition of a group. Many people get confused the idea that there must exists an identity element in the set, vs for all $g\in G \ \exists ! e \in G$ s.t. $g*e=e*g=g$. If we used this second statement for the definition of a group, then the empty set would be a group(by vacuous truth).

Comment: Identity element is usually understood as an attribute of a structure (constant ≃ 0-ary operation), not as an axiom. Certainly, empty set can’t be a model for any mathematical structure with constants.